# QML Qvariant from custom class

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qlist, qvariant

I have my custom C++ class: `Media.h`:

```
#ifndef MEDIA_H
#define MEDIA_H

class Media
{

public:
    explicit Media();
    virtual ~Media();

    void setAllMedia(QString id, QString type, QString media, QString meta);


signals:


private slots:


private:
    QString _id;
    QString _type;
    QString _media;
    QString _meta;
};

#endif
```

in other QML file, i have some code wich reads very good values from a QML variant like this: `main.ml`:

```
property variant medias:[[]]
...
medias = [{
    "id": "7",
    "type": "image",
    "media": "1451138132567e9c544fc64.png",
    "meta": null
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "type": "image",
    "media": "1451150881567ece21bb77e.png",
    "meta": null
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "type": "video",
    "media": "1451150924567ece4c68775.png",
    "meta": null
}]
```

The problem is that I need to dynamically create the variant medias array from C++ and send it to QML.

I have some signals to send the medias array from C++ to QML but this array is inside `QList<Media>`. How can I convert it to `QVariant` in order to be readable by QML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store custom classes inside a QVariant object if you register these classes with [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE).

This will make the conversion possible from `Media` to `QVariant` in your C++ code, but the `Media` class will not be usable in QML as you would like.

Instead, just create a `QHash<QString, QVariant>` or `QMap<QString, QVariant>` for storing the properties since they are automatically inverted (see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object)).